# Value getting changed in the iteration before the call begins

Tags: c#, .net, scope, asynchronous

I've the following code in my app.

```
MyEventHandler handler = null; //Declare the handler

foreach (string pname in group)
{
  handler = getHandler(pname); //Get the handler
  if(handler == null)
  {                        
      throw new KeyNotFoundException("No user " + pname + " could be found");
  }
  //invoke the handler
  handler.BeginInvoke(this, e, new AsyncCallback(EndAsync), null);
}
```

So i get the handler and call `BeginInvoke` method. But before `BeginInvoke` gets called it goes to next iteration and the handler value gets changed. So the `BeginInvoke` is getting involved for this new handler.

Hope you get my point. So how can i eliminate this issue? I dont want to call sleep after `BeginInvoke` as i feel it is a loss of time.

Any ideas?

**Update1**
I'm pretty sure that the handler object gets changed before BeginInvoke() is called. I guess that the BeginInvoke takes some time to create a separate thread to call the other function.

**Update2**
This code is in a WCF service and the clients call a function which in turn makes use of this function. I've separate handlers stored in my server for each client. The WCF service has a duplex contract with separates sessions for the client. I see that after this function is executed same user is getting invoked twice. But i put a break point and debug it (which gives the BeginInvoke the necessary time to call the function) it works "PERFECTLY". I very sure i faced this problem in threading too where i create multiple threads in a loop. If the thread delegate has parameters a,b,c and if you change it at the beginning of the next iteration the same behavior occurs. I dono how many of you people have experienced this issue before. If i put a Sleep() or if i make a copy of the handler and invoke it using copy it'll work.

**Update3**

Okie, i've tested it now. I just added the Thread.Sleep() as follows.

```
chatTo.BeginInvoke(this, e, new AsyncCallback(EndAsync), null);
Thread.Sleep(500);
```

and it is working like a charm. Any thoughts?

**Update 4**

I've created a thread sample demonstrating the issue and [i've uploaded it here](http://cid-3ef70212ea082a2d.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/ThreadIssueSample.zip). I hope a solution to this will resolve my issue too. Kindly check the sample.

Comment: How do you verify that "handler" changes in an incorrect manner? It's not that I don't believe you but I think you're looking at the wrong thing here. Are the right delegates being called?

Comment: Is that `lock` there for any reason? If so, you should probably include the other lines involving `handler` inside the lock as well.

Comment: @Lasse I'm sure that the same handler is getting called twice because of the behavior of the application. I got this SAME PROBLEM IN THREADING ONCE. I had to have a local variable and assign it to it before invoking the thread. What i learnt is that the value changes in the next iteration before the actuall thread or an asynchronous delegate is invoked.

Comment: @deltreme Sorry, it is a redundant code. Had few write operations on a dictionary before inside that block. Code edited.

Comment: I agree. We need to see what else is manipulating `handler`. Also perhaps an explanation of what you are trying to solve - we could perhaps suggest a better/different approach.

Comment: Could the same handler be twice in the collection?

Comment: Are you using `handler` anywhere other than the shown code?

Comment: Can you produce a small and complete example that has these problems?

Comment: Or, if you can't do that, can you post the actual code? And not code that you've simplified for our benefit? Often when people ask "why does this code not work", it turns out that there is no problems with the code after simplifying it, but the original code has problems, which we're not seeing.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: Exactly - The above code can't produce the behaviour being described otherwise there's something very broken with threading as a whole, which would go far beyond a narrow situation like this.

Comment: Also, please edit the code so that it makes sense. The code as shown will not run at all as it stands now, since it will always throw exceptions from within the lock clause. I stand by my earlier request, **show us the original, unmodified, unsimplified, code.**

Comment: The code you've posted is to an altogether different problem, or you've deliberately confused us by "simplifying" the code. You have a problem with captured values and anonymous methods, not with the handler variable (or a similar problem). I'll provide an answer.

Comment: @Lasse - 1. No the same handler can't be twice in the collection. Because the issue is not consistent. Sometimes the message gets sent to the correct clients (if you have studied my #Update2). That handler is a local variable and is not used anywhere else.

Comment: Please look at my answer before moving on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156682/value-getting-changed-in-the-iteration-before-the-call-begins-c-net/3157918#3157918

Comment: Removed the lock. That was stupid, i know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see why this would happen - the code you posted cannot possibly reproduce the behaviour you describe.  It's entirely reasonable that the BeginInvoke call might not actual do anything straight away, and that the next iteration might occur before you actually see that call do anything - since it will be queued for processing by a worker thread.

***This doesn't mean that a different handler is being invoked - the handler to be invoked is captured as soon as BeginInvoke is called, so it won't matter if the local variable changes afterwards***.

Also - why have you got the lock here?  Unless multiple threads are doing this processing at the same time over the same enumerable (in which case why would you do that) I can't see any reason why you would lock.

I would also say that if you're judging this behaviour by what you see in the debugger, then you shouldn't worry - you'll get 'interesting' results from the debugger by doing this, and with the multiple threads in the mix it's important to switch threads in the 'Threads' debugger window.

The question is - does your program actually do what you expect?  If so, but you're seeing this strange behaviour whilst debugging - then that's entirely normal.

As a few comments have stated - the code you posted can't be exactly what's producing the problem.  If, for example, 'handler' is a local variable shared between multiple threads that then perform this iteration then, yes, you could get something like this.  But a variable local to a method can only be modified (and indeed read) by the same thread that's currently *in that method*; the only exception to that rule being if the `handler` reference is then passed out to another threaded method as a `ref`.

Comment: Regardless of whether BeginInvoke happens at once, it takes a snapshot during the initial startup call (the one being made from the shown code), so even if handler changes in the loop before BeginInvoke has started executing the code in the background, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Hmmm. May be i'm wrong but i really doubt what you're saying. Why does the application work fine when i put a sleep or do it with a copy object?

Comment: It is impossible to say why it works as you expect when you add a sleep because **we're not seeing the whole picture**. All I can tell you is that when you do `handler.BeginInvoke`, changes to handler after BeginInvoke has returned, but before it starts executing the code in the background **does not matter**. Which handler to execute in the background was copied when BeginInvoke was executed, `handler` is not used by BeginInvoke so changes to that variable **does not matter**.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Karlsen. Let me dig in more.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: re your first comment - that's exactly what I said at the end of the first paragraph. From the original code that was posted, there's no way that local handler variable (unless it's a class member, or perhaps a ref argument passed to the method and the caller is on a separate thread) can be getting modified by anything other than the loop itself, in which case, I question whether the behaviour the OP describes is actually happening at all.

Comment: Yep, I think I posted my comment in the wrong comment box here :) I was not commenting your answer.

Comment: I'm marking this as answer because this is the real answer as i've understood - "the handler to be invoked is captured as soon as BeginInvoke is called, so it won't matter if the local variable changes afterwards."

Answer (score 5):

Ok, after your fourth edit you provide us with an example, that exhibits a problem, sure, but not **the problem you're asking for help about**.

What you're saying in the question is that:

- I use BeginInvoke on a delegate variable, then change the variable, and somehow my delegates are invoked twice

What you exhibit in the posted code is that:

- I capture a loop variable in an anonymous method, and somehow I use the wrong variable value

**THESE ARE NOT THE SAME PROBLEM!**

The reason for your posted code misbehaving is that the code in question actually looks like this under the hood:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    ... create delegate, capture i, spawn thread
```

Here you're capturing the same variable for all the threads. If a thread doesn't start executing before the loop changes the variable, then yes, you will see the "incorrect value" for that variable.

However, if you change the code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int j = i;
    ThreadStart threadStartObj = new ThreadStart(
        delegate { PrintValueThreadFunction(j, j); });
                                            ^
                                            |
                                            +-- use j instead of i here
```

Then you will capture a "fresh" variable for each thread, which won't get changed.

So, the question remains. Is this the problem you're having? If so, then *shame on you*, next time, **don't simplify the problem**. You're wasting people's time, most of all your own. Had you posted code like the above to begin with you would've had an answer (or a duplicate question pointing to existing answers, there's plenty) within a couple of minutes.

If this is not the problem you're having, you're still having problem with an event handler like in the original code being invoked more than once, go back and produce a better example project.

Comment: The sad thing here is that when I looked at the code in notepad I immediately knew what the problem was, as would about 100+ other people here on SO within the first minute, without actually compiling or executing the code at all.

Comment: Firstly, i know i dint give the exact code of my issue. Thats why i've quoted "I hope a solution to this will resolve my issue too. Kindly check the sample." I just guessed whether i have the same problem in my code since BeginInvoke creates a new thread. Thats what i've quoted in #Update1.

Comment: Also in Update2 i have quoted the same thing you have said here, which is to make a copy of the variable. And, i've not simplified my code much. I've just posted a part of the code. May be it is not enough, i understand. But i've told that handler is a local variable and i dont change it anywhere else. I'm not that bad :).

Comment: But making a copy of handler wouldn't make a difference, because in your code you're not using anonymous methods or capturing variables. It is not the same issue. Whether you're making copy of handler or not, in the code shown in your question, has no bearing on the problem at all. The problem is entirely different, and has to do with anonymous delegates and captured variables, not with BeginInvoke. In short, don't simplify for our benefit until we ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having some other problem... handler.BeginInvoke can't be called after next iteration, you're still in the same thread...

Comment: I'm not using that handler object anywhere else. When you call the BeginInvoke will the control of the application waits till the BeginInvoke invokes the delegate?

Comment: No, it will not, but BeginInvoke has taken a copy of the current value of handler, and will not refer to the variable it came from, only to its copy, which means that even if you change handler right after returning from BeginInvoke, **it shouldn't matter**

Comment: Hello Karlsen. I've updated the post. Download the thread sample from here - http://cid-3ef70212ea082a2d.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/ThreadIssueSample.zip