# C# Starting new Threads/Tasks in a for loop results in sending the same value as a parameter to the method in the threa

Tags: c#, multithreading, loops

I was playing around with Tasks and Threads and saw this weird behaviour. I was wondering if someone can explain to me why is this behaviour occurring?

I have this for loop:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
                //Thread.Sleep(1000);
            OutputThis output = new OutputThis();
                Task myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { output.doThis(i); });
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Already out of the loop!");
            Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

And the method doThis(int y) is just a Console Output with a Thread Sleep:

```
        public void doThis(int y)
    {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Number: " + y);
    }
```

Now if the for loop executes with the Thread.Sleep(1000); it will output (with some small variations) like this:

```
Number: 1
Number: 2
Number: 3
Number: 4
Already out of the loop!
Number: 5
Number: 6
Number: 6
Number: 8
Number: 9
Number: 9
```

But without the Thread.Sleep in the for loop it will always look like this:

```
Already out of the loop!
Number: 10
Number: 10
Number: 10
Number: 10
Number: 10
Number: 10
Number: 10
Number: 10
Number: 10
Number: 10
```

Again, why does the Thread.Sleep make such a big difference?
(Also, the same behaviour occurs when using Threads);

Comment: Try using Parallel.For https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop

Comment: It is a standard bug, google "closing over the loop variable considered harmful".  Simply add `var copy = i;` and pass copy to avoid the bug.

Comment: You have stumbled into the standard "captured loop variable reaches end before first thread starts" issue. We have many such questions on Stack Overflow already. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3157918) of the marked duplicate for one such example.

Comment: The `Thread.Sleep(1000)` in the main loop makes the main loop slow enough that the other taks are able to start and see the value of `i` before the loop is over. If you remove `Thread.Sleep(1000)`, for when the other tasks start they see the value of `i` after the loop has complete... because the loop has completed. Addendum: It is a race condition. You should not rely on Thread.Sleep. In addition, if you copy the value of `i` to a new variable inside the loop and give that to the tasks, you will not see this effect, or more precisely the other tasks will not see `i`.

Comment: the phenomenon called [closures](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) is responsible for this. `i` should not exist after the loop, but it is needed at the point in time when the task has to be started. So `i` will be kept in memory. And as @Theraot already said if the task is started after the loop has finished it will encounter `i` as having it's last value which is in your loop `10`. The point in time when this line: `..Task.Factory.StartNew...` is executed is not the same as when the task/process really starts.